# ListAdapter error

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Could someone tell me what is wrong with this piece of code?

It is supposed to be a ListView from an XML file that is then referred to in Java.
Alas, it crashes my application every time it enters the Menu class.

```
public class Menu extends ListActivity {

    String Name_for_classes[] = {"- 1-9 Tabels -", "- 10-19 Tabels -", "- 20-29 Tabels -" };
    String Tabel_classes[] = {"First", "Second", "Third"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.menu, Name_for_classes));
        ListView list = getListView();
        list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: From a quick glance, you're not setting your list adapter to your ListView.

Comment: Why you need this? Class StartingClass = Class.forName("com.sapphire.android." + Classes);. Post exception stack also.

Comment: It is actually irrelevant for the question.

Comment: Please post the stack trace. Also, you mentioned an xml file, though no layout is loaded here, and generally isn't in a ListActivity.

Comment: LogCat says: You must supply a resource ID for a TextView. And my xml file for the listview looks like this: 

    <ListView 
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp" >
    </ListView>

Comment: Do you have any other xml files in your project? From the LogCat output, sounds like you have a TextView somewhere in your project that you have not assigned an id to. Also, don't forget to setContentView(R.layout.yourxmlfilename); -- That needs to be in your onCreate, after super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, let's assume you have your ListView in an XML file called my_listview.xml.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_listview.xml);
    ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    ArrayAdapter<String> yourAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Name_for_classes);
    list.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
}
```

Comment: By doing this:  @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.my_listview);
 ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
 ArrayAdapter<String> namesadapter = new ArrayAdapter< String >(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Name_for_classes);
 list.setAdapter(namesadapter);
 } Fixed the R.id.list error. But the app still crashes.

Comment: Didn't notice you were extending ListActivity. Try using a plain Activity, and don't forget to declare it in your AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Sapphire - make sure to mark the answer that helped you as correct.  The user gets credit for it on Stack Overflow, and other users can immediately identify what fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is in R.layout.menu, but guessing by the naming its the activity layout. This should be used with setContentView(R.layout.menu) in onCreate. The layout that is passed into the ArrayAdapter is the TextView you are using to populate the listview.

Comment: If I understand your answer. I need to setContentView(R.layout.menu); And then in the adapter say: setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list, Name_for_classes)); But when I do that eclipse indicates R.layout.list as an error.

Comment: Don't pass in the listview resource either. The resource you should be passing in is its own layout that the adapter will use to inflate and create cells for the listview.

Comment: Replace "R.layout.list" with "android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1"

Comment: Yeah, but by doing that, I don't even need to create an xml layout. And I need that.

Comment: What do you mean you don't need to create a XML layout? android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 is setting the style of your ListView.

Comment: I do need to create a xml layout, make a listview, reference it in java. And final purpose, I can make padding on the listview.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to call the setContentView in your onCreate method, so your listview is not referenced yet.

When you use setContentView, it is equivalent as sayin 'for this activity I want to use the template 'myTemplate.xml'
After that, you have to 'linked' your java ListView attribute to the listview declared in your template.

Comment: You mean like this:  @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.menu);
  setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter <String>(this, R.layout.list, Name_for_classes)); - Eclipse just indicates a error under .list

Comment: the example in the next comment is right for me.(comment from bschultz)